# replacing a word inside a sublist

Tags: python, parsing, replace, sublist

I am not very experienced with python
I have a parse tree list structure that contains a list with sublists inside sublists and so on.
I need to replace some words in the tree with *RARE*.
I have written a recursive procedure that allows me to find the word and to determine if they meet the condition for replacement.
I am stuck at how to actually replace them in the original file.

```
import json
s_tring=json.loads(open("tree.example").readline())
def word_find(s_tring):
    for item in s_tring:
        #check if end of tree, always with character "."
        if "." in item[0]:
            break
        else:
            #words only appear in sublists of length 2
            #some of those are lists of strings ['a','b'] (word is 'b')
            #others are list with sublists ['a',['b','c']] (word is 'c')
            if len(item)==2 and type(item)==list:
                if type(item[1]) == list:
                    word-to_evaluate = item[1][1]
                    #need to replace it in tree.example if condition met
                else:
                    word_to_evaluate = item[1]
                    #need to replace it in tree.example if condition met
            else:
                #recursive call to continue drilling down the tree
                if len(item)==3:
                    word_find(item)
    return

word_find(s_tring)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing to file at all. You should reopen your file for writing(or open another one). You can do it like this:

```
with codecs.open('result_file.json', 'w', 'utf-8') as output_file:
    output_file.write(json.dumps(your_data))
```

Also you should close file descriptor you opened with open()

```
fd = open(filename, filemode)
# do your stuff to fd
fd.close()
```

Alternate syntax to this(python2.5+) is

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fd:
    lines = fd.readlines() # or anything else to do with fd
```

And one more thing - you are reading just one line with .readline() method.

Comment: sorry, the code I posted just reads a single parse tree to test my code, also I am not outputting anything yet, as I do not know how to replace the word in the sublist.

Comment: I find primary problem to be kind of weird. Think of that - are you using right kind of data? Is your input data a binary tree? If it is, you can use less clumbersome representation, for example: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2001-May/005456.html